# SQL - Get list based on column from table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am having a table named "Company".

In that a column "Product" which is delimited with '|' (Pipeline symbol) like "12|13|14|15".

I want to get the list from this table where the Product is "12".

that is Company with Product "12",even the company may have another product also.

I want to get the list by splitting the column.

please help me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this,

```
SELECT   *
FROM     Company
WHERE    '|' + Product + '|' LIKE '%|' + '12' + '|%'
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/75421/1)

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like

```
SELECT *
FROM   Company
WHERE  Product LIKE '12'
OR     Product LIKE '12|%'
OR     Product LIKE '%|12|%'
OR     Product LIKE '%|12'
```

But you should probably think about changing your schema so that you have a table called CompanyProduct that has many rows for each Company.